# Como evitar que una clave foránea se repita en un factory de laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito que cada dirección se le asigne a un usuario. Es decir que cada user_id tenga un usuario único.

```
$factory->define(Address::class, function (Faker $faker) {

$country = App\Country::all()->random();
$community = $country->communities->random();
$province = $community->provinces->random();
$area = $community->area;

return [
    'user_id' => App\User::all()->random()->id,
    'postcode' => $faker->postcode,
    'country_id' => $country->id,
    'community_id' => $community->id, 
    'province_id' => $province->id,
    'area_id' => $area->id, 
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumiendo que los id de los usuarios sean consecutivos y que inicien en 1, la solución está utilizando unique() y el método numberBetween():

```
'user_id' => $faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, App\User::count()),
```

Un poco de documentación por aquí: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#modifiers